# Magento 2 : Priority of translation, proper way

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, csv, localisation

I'm trying to set up a spanish-english store.

I have my dictionary that I want to reutilize for other stores. It has all translations in spanish. I install this dictionary on `app/i18n/vendor/es_es/`
At this point is all okay. I have standard translations so my store is on english-spanish.

But now, you install the template and customizations. Typical change is you want "wish list" instead of "add to wish list".

You can fix this easily creating i18n folder on theme folder and creating en_US csv file to customize all phrases you want.

But if you try to do the same on other languages, creating for example es_ES csv file, it won't take effect. Seems that on spanish it priorizes my dictionary.

To be clear, I have this 2 csv files on my theme:

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv`
`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/es_ES.csv`

The thing is, `en_US.csv` is working but `es_ES.csv` doesn't.

What can I do to priorize the translations on theme?

Or what is the proper way to achieve my objective? having a standard dictionary and then customizing some phrases.

I don't want to use inline-translations.

Comment: I have the same problem. I created a xx_XX.csv in my template folder but it does not generate it. I just see en_US.csv in my static and preprocessed files. Is this the same for you too?

Comment: Did you setup the storeView on that language? In my case is retrieving `es_ES` static files, the problem is Magento is getting spanish translations from my dictionary not from `es_ES.csv` which is on theme folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, language pack translations have priority over theme translations.

This is going to be fixed in Magento 2.2, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/7142

Comment: And when will they release it? Are you sure it's 2.2? so there will be no 2.1.7 version?

Comment: The current develop branch is what goes into `2.2`, to be released mid/end of Q2 (no specific date yet). There will be `2.1.7` but just as part of the 2.1 LTS branch https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1-develop - and Magento did not backport this fix

Comment: Okay, so, for now I understand we should use a theme translation... because using dictionary will override everything

Comment: It's not in 2.1.7 unfortunately. Is there a temporary fix ? Somewhere to set priority explicitly ?

Comment: @maxagaz if you look at the file changes in the linked pull request, it's a reordering of lines in `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Translate.php`, nothing more. You can patch or override the file by yourself until the real update comes

Comment: @FabianSchmengler It worked, thanks for the hint!!

Comment: @FabianSchmengler  Is it all fixed now? in m2.4 we can assume the theme translations have more priority over language packs?